# How do I use SMTP on a test development server?

Tags: apache, email, ssl, dns, smtp

I am building an ecommerce website on a local Windows 7 pro (Apache/php) test server with a self-signed SSL. I have the mydomain.com in the hosts file redirecting to localhost - so far so good.

When I try to use the email function of the ecommerce software via Gmail smtp, I am getting an SSL error:

```
[23-Apr-2018 03:00:06 America/New_York] Connection failed. Error #2: stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed [C:\Apache24\htdocs\includes\classes\vendors\PHPMailer\class.smtp.php line 379]
[23-Apr-2018 03:00:06 America/New_York] SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
[23-Apr-2018 03:00:06 America/New_York] CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
```

I thought about just getting a cheap CA SSL and installing it on the server but I'm not sure this will work, since the Gmail smtp server is obviously not using my hosts file. This is just a guess at this point.

Question I'd like answered is, 1, will installing CA cert resolve the issue, and 2. if not, what is your strategy to have a functional email on a test server with domain in hosts file?

Thank you,

David

Comment: What is exactly the action that is triggering this error?

Comment: It was the smtp connection script. Solved it by setting veryfy_peer false, since it is a test server.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to the function responsible for smtp connection. Warning, only to be used on completely secure environment, your own test server, never on a live server.

```
$options["ssl"]=array("verify_peer"=>false,"verify_peer_name"=>false,"allow_self_signed"=>true);
```